Why did this Rust code from December 18, 2021 compile?
At this blog post the writer shows that Rust won't allow the capture of a variable by reference:
use std::thread;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicI32, Ordering};

struct ThreadSafeCounter {
    count: AtomicI32,
}

impl ThreadSafeCounter {
    fn increment(&mut self) { self.count.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst); }
}

pub fn main() {
    let n = 10;
    let mut counter = ThreadSafeCounter { count: AtomicI32::new(0) };
    let mut threads = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..n {
        threads.push(thread::spawn( || {
            // Rust won't allow this.  We are attempting to mutably borrow
            // the same value multiple times.
            counter.increment();
        }));
    }
    for thread in threads { thread.join(); }
    println!("{}", counter.count.load(Ordering::SeqCst));
}

And then makes one change to the code, and says:

The Rust answer to thread-safety is to allow mutation on an immutable
reference. Rust calls this “interior mutability.” With one small
change, the previous example compiles and works as expected:

use std::thread;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicI32, Ordering};

struct ThreadSafeCounter {
    count: AtomicI32,
}

impl ThreadSafeCounter {
    // increment() uses "interior mutability": it accepts an immutable
    // reference, but ultimately mutates the value.
    fn increment(&self) { self.count.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst); }
}

pub fn main() {
    let n = 10;
    let mut counter = ThreadSafeCounter { count: AtomicI32::new(0) };
    let mut threads = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..n {
        threads.push(thread::spawn( || {
            counter.increment();
        }));
    }
    for thread in threads { thread.join(); }
    println!("{}", counter.count.load(Ordering::SeqCst));
}

The error I get is:

to force the closure to take ownership of counter (and any other
referenced variables), use the move keyword:

Is this supposed to compile? The post was written in December 18, 2021.

The blog post is incorrect. That code doesn't compile under any Rust version or edition (2015, 2018, or 2021), due to lifetimes: counter lives on main's stack, so it will eventually go out of scope. The spawned threads need access as long as they are executing. This is enforced by the 'static bound for thread::spawn's argument. The borrow checker's static analysis can't see that the threads finish using counter and are joined before main returns.
The most straight-forward way to make it compile is to move a new Arc-reference of the counter into each spawned thread.
use std::thread;
use std::sync::{atomic::{AtomicI32, Ordering}, Arc};

struct ThreadSafeCounter {
    count: AtomicI32,
}

impl ThreadSafeCounter {
    // increment() uses "interior mutability": it accepts an immutable
    // reference, but ultimately mutates the value.
    fn increment(&self) { self.count.fetch_add(1, Ordering::SeqCst); }
}

pub fn main() {
    let n = 10;
    let mut counter = Arc::new(ThreadSafeCounter { count: AtomicI32::new(0) });
    let mut threads = Vec::new();
    for _ in 0..n {
        let counter = Arc::clone(&counter);
        threads.push(thread::spawn(move || {
            counter.increment();
        }));
    }
    for thread in threads { thread.join(); }
    println!("{}", counter.count.load(Ordering::SeqCst));
}

Another way to make it compile is to use scoped threads. A recent addition to the standard library, they allow borrowing variables from the caller's stack by forcibly joining all spawned threads before returning to the caller.
let counter = ThreadSafeCounter { count: AtomicI32::new(0) };
thread::scope(|scope| {
    for _ in 0..n {
        scope.spawn( || {
            counter.increment();
        });
    }
});
println!("{}", counter.count.load(Ordering::SeqCst));

When writing threaded code, you are more likely to see normal threads exchanging messages or sharing reference-counted data than you are to see scoped threads borrowing data. That's because normal threads are more flexible and support thread pooling.
